# contract question regarding not meeting deadline

Tags: contract-law

I signed a very general contract to do some work with a contractor. The contract specified that the work would be completed in 30 days. It also gave "the owner" the right to terminate the contract if the company did not supply the people and materials in time to complete the project. Within the 30 days, the project manager declared that the project was done. The work was done poorly and they did not do all they promised and left off some of the work they had decided unilaterally that they would not leave out. It has now been over 60 days since the beginning effective date of the contract and the problems have not been resolved. I had to argue with different people in their hierarchy and the VP decided I was correct in my complaints and claims they plan to do what is needed to fulfill the contract. I am very sour over this and really do not want them on my property anymore. Does this lapse of deadlines affect the validity of the contract?

I asked about other aspects of this contract earlier. They made up a last name for me on the contract and also have the wrong address of the work on the contract. It was humorous, on the last meeting at the property, one of their people went to the wrong address from the contract.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested finishing dates in contracts carry little weight, unless they are expressed clearly via a [time is of the essence clause](https://www.hahnlaw.com/insights/time-is-of-the-essence-or-is-it/). A 30 day delay in completion is not too surprising in the ordinary home-reno business. Obviously, they can't get away with repeatedly declaring "We'll get you on the schedule as soon as possible" for 5 years, but what constitutes an unreasonable delay depends on the local facts. Lawyering up could speed things up: even writing a simple formal letter that implies that legal action will be your next step could facilitate a solution.